# What can cause massive overexposure on a Canon PowerShot A470?

Tags: canon, powershot, overexposure

I have a Canon PowerShot A470. One day, while taking photos, it has gone from taking perfect pictures to being massively overexposed (almost white) pictures; however, this is not a problem with taking videos - they are absolutely fine.

I have gone through all the settings that I can find (most importantly, changed the exposure done to as low as possible - no help). Does anyone have any suggestions, or is something fundamentally broken?

Comment: reset settings to factory default? (somewhere in the menu...). Check also the dial : are you not in "Bulb" mode ? (the dial can move unexpectedly...)

Comment: I don't believe the A470 has a bulb mode :-) It's a very basic P&S.

Comment: @PhilipKendall indeed. But it could be set on "Scene" with some long exposure scene? or "Manual" (= semi-auto) with some weird setting? returning to "default" to test the camera would then be a good step.

Comment: Move your dial to Auto mode (i.e. the camera icon, without an M next to it), to make sure you're not in some crazy mode. Does that help? Now take a picture in a dark room without flash. Is the photo dark (as expected) or still overexposed? If the latter is true, you might have a light leak from the LCD to the sensor or with the analog-to-digital converter. If not, it's probably your exposure meter that's off.

Comment: I've tried resetting to default, changing the "scene", using auto, using manual and changing the exposure.

I've tried taking a photo underneath tables / behind settees, which should be very dark, but the pictures are still bright (pretty good actually, considering!) - unfortunately, in normal light, they are mostly white!

Comment: Is there some way of doing a hard reset (there isn't even a physical reset button that I can find)? Sometimes shorting it works (but may this damage it otherwise)?

Comment: Also strange that the video works without any problems...

Comment: Actually try taking a photo in a completely dark room, with your hand over the LCD so it doesn't light up the room. Are photos still bright in that scenario?

Comment: When it's completely dark, it doesn't light up. When there is some light, however, it does make it a lot brighter.

Comment: Highly likely a faulty lens.

Comment: @BBking Not denying it, but why would a faulty lens work fine in video mode?

Comment: Because it's not using the mechanical shutter in video mode. It could be repairable (simply a stuck shutter lever) but who can be bothered dismantling a compact lens these days?

Comment: @SmileySam Is there a reason you reverted the changes to the question? I'm probably biased, but I think they were an improvement.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - personally I liked it. To be honest, I don't really mind. If you'd like to put it back in, then that's fine! =P

Comment: Mine is doing the same thing Kelly

Answer (score 1):

I probably know an answer.

Cameras almost always have aperture open if not recording anything - to make the optical viewfinder brighter or electronic viewfinder display better image.

Then, cameras close aperture for each exposure to arbitrary or automatically selected F value.

Cameras know how much light will be cut if they close down to F if they know the open objective speed.

Now, if the aperture is stuck in the middle, camera will always overexpose photos when set F is bigger than initial F, and will do so even more if the aperture does not move at all.

The video mode may be unaffected because in this mode camera meters in real time, just the noise may be bumped.

Comment: Interesting idea. If it is the case, any idea how I'd fix it? =D

Comment: @smiley-sam: you'd better check if it's the case - look into the objective and see whether aperture moves. If it does not move at all, you may be sure in that it is the case.

What next? I would take it apart and see what is wrong. The technology is quite tough nowadays and most malfunctions are caused with small defects - like, big dust particle got somewhere into mechanics.

Comment: @smiley-sam: or, the ribbon cable may be damaged, and that would be even easier to repair (give that you have a source for spares).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into that. Need to find the camera again first! =P

Comment: @smiley-sam: it is sure worth it, at least for trying [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/A470). You may as well remove IR mirror from there.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem and it is the ribbon cable to the electonic shutter that has broken. Sadly it is not an easy fix as the camera is difficult to dismantle and ribbon cables are difficult to solder.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with My Canon Powershot SX430IS. The image goes whitewashed after a particular zoom range. Just before that range there is no problem and i can hear the shutter release sound. Butter just after passing that range no shutter clicking noise and images are over exposed. There is no problem with Videos. Something to do with aperture. Went to canon Master service center. The service center seems very familiar with this issue. And for Powershot XXX series they only provide replacements, No repairs.  I am out of warranty by 3 weeks. So now i have to pay RS. 8000+ for replacement. And i bought the camera 2 years back for 12999.